# Set custom headers to all volley requests

Tags: java, android, android-volley

Overriding getHeaders() works to add customs headers if necessary to the requests.
But what if X header is always needed to be set? for example an static auth token.

```
JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest(URL, new JSONObject(params),
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    setFollowButton(item);
                }
            }, null){
        @Override
        public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
            HashMap<String, String> headers = new HashMap<String, String>();
            headers.put("Authorization", "Token XXXXXXXXXXXX");
            return headers;
        }
};

Application.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
```

Can be the header added to the request sent to the addToRequestQueue method instead overwriting it every time I write a request?

Comment: why not create a base request, and then extend that request for each new request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the best way is extend the `HttpStack` sub-class which you choose to use, then intercepting the `performRequest()` method, put your global headers inside it.

```
public class MyHurlStack extends HurlStack {
    @Override
    public HttpResponse performRequest(
            Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders)
            throws IOException, AuthFailureError {

        Map<String, String> headers = request.getHeaders();
        // put your global headers
        headers.put("Via", "netroid");
        headers.put("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        headers.put("Origin", "http://netroid.cn/");

        return super.performRequest(request, additionalHeaders);
    }
}

public class MyHttpClientStack extends HttpClientStack {
    public MyHttpClientStack(HttpClient client) {
        super(client);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPrepareRequest(HttpUriRequest request) throws IOException {
        // put your global headers
        request.setHeader("Via", "netroid");
        request.setHeader("Accept-Charset", "UTF-8");
        request.setHeader("Origin", "http://netroid.cn/");
        super.onPrepareRequest(request);
    }
}
```

when `RequestQueue` initializing, use the customize HttpStack instead of.

```
if (stack == null) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9) {
        stack = new HurlStack();
    } else {
        stack = new MyHttpClientStack(AndroidHttpClient.newInstance(userAgent));
    }
}

Network network = new BasicNetwork(stack);
```

Comment: To use `HurlStack` just call `requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext(), stack);` Simple and clean!

Comment: Map<String, String> headers is nowhere used or returned in HurlStack? How come headers will work then?

Comment: @RafiqueMohammed, is correct. This does not work with the default Request#getHeaders() implementation because by default it returns an immutable empty set. Trying to add stuff to this set will throw an `com.android.volley.VolleyError: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException`. So, obviously this doesn't work. However, if you override the getHeaders() in your own classes to return a mutable instance variable then you can do that, but it requires that you then extend this class for all your requests. Not sure why they do this in Volley..

Answer (score 0):

After a long search on how to add custom headers on each request with the volley android library,
I used HurlStack as bellow, hope it helps someone.

```
private static class MyHurl extends HurlStack{

        @Override
        public HttpResponse executeRequest(Request<?> request, Map<String, String> additionalHeaders){

            Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>(additionalHeaders);
            headers.put("authKey","myauthkey");

            try {
                return super.executeRequest(request, headers);
            } catch (IOException e) {

            } catch (AuthFailureError authFailureError) {
            }

            return null;
        }
    }
```