# Android Volley not modifying headers for POST request

Tags: android, http-headers, android-volley

I am trying to call a RESTful API in my Android app using Volley. The API requires that for each request you pass in a special header (X-AUTH-TOKEN).

I found that I could do this for GET requests by overriding the getHeaders method from the Request class.

However when I try to do this with a POST request, I find that the header is not appended / received by the server.

This is the class I am using to create the request

```
public class AuthenticatedStringRequest extends StringRequest {


public AuthenticatedStringRequest(int method, String url, Response.Listener<String> listener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {
    super(method, url, listener, errorListener);
}

@Override
public Map<String, String> getHeaders() {
    Map<String, String> headers = new HashMap<>();
    headers.put("X-AUTH-TOKEN", Constants.AUTH_TOKEN);
    return headers;
}
}
```

Is there a different method of adding special headers with POST requests on Volley?

Comment: see if this is of any help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24877292/set-custom-headers-to-all-volley-requests